# http query string: question mark becomes %3

Tags: go, url

Attempting to append to an existing queryString, but '?' that proceeds the query string is being replaced with '%3'

```
 server := "server.com"
 endpoint:= "/buildWithParameters?token=<top_secret>" 

// concat server and build job
    u, err := url.Parse(server)
    u.Path = path.Join(u.Path, endpoint)
    endpoint := u.String()

    // since we are appending to existing querystring, request is needed for parsing
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", endpoint, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Error creating post request: (%v)", err)
    }

    // read existing query string
    q := req.URL.Query()


    q.Add("key", "value")

    req.URL.RawQuery = q.Encode()


    log.Println(req.URL.String())
```

The output is:

```
https://server.com/job/jobbyjob/buildWithParameters%3Ftoken=<top_secret>?key=value
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're appending the query string to the path, so the library is correctly escaping `?` to make for a valid URL. If you want `token=<top_secret>` to be treated as part of the query, you need to add it to the query instead:

```
endpoint:= "/buildWithParameters" 

// ... 

q.Add("token", "<top_secret>")
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, the path library was the problem.  I switched to using .ResolveReference instead and it's working marvelous

Answer (score 1):

As @Flimzy pointed out, it was the Path library causing my issue.  The following base.ResolveReference() method resolved:

```
// concat server and build job
u, err := url.Parse(server)
u.Path = path.Join(u.Path, endpoint)
endpoint := u.String()
```

replaced with:

```
// concat server and build job
base, err := url.Parse(server)
endpoint, err := url.Parse(endpoint)
endpoint = base.ResolveReference(endpoint)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating it with `url.Parse`, then appending the query string to the path (which it's handling correctly, by escaping it). If you do it the other way around (construct your complete URL, then parse it), it can do its job:

```
server := "server.com"
endpoint := "/buildWithParameters?token=<top_secret>" 

// concat server and build job
u, err := url.Parse(path.Join(server, endpoint))
```